# IP name and path is showing on window

Tags: javascript, window, location, title

I have to open a pdf file in a new window. But when it open in new window, it shows the full path including ip address as page title. My need is I have to give a title manually.

Comment: How are you "opening" the pdf file in a new window?

Comment: Currently i open it using window.open()

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to change the title of the popup window would be to embed the PDF file (e.g. using an iframe) in a "wrapper" webpage with the desired title, and then open the wrapper page in your popup. Something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset=utf-8>
<title>Form 1040</title>
<style type="text/css">
BODY { margin: 0; padding: 0 }
IFRAME { position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%; border: 0 }
</style>
<body>
<iframe src="http://www.irs.gov/file_source/pub/irs-pdf/f1040.pdf"></iframe>
</body>
```